# Nginx proxy_pass url with # doesnot work

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

```
proxy_pass "http://192.168.x.y:8080/app/sample#/dashboard/Revenue-Dashboard/"
```

When I set the above url in nginx server location, the portion of the url after # is getting ignored when the proxy call is fired.

Url which is proxied becomes : `"http://192.168.x.y:8080/app/sample"`

Any pointers?

Comment: Sure. The `#` is never sent to the server, or anything trailing it. This is just useful for the javascript on the page. Everything should be resolved client-side and then the proper request URI sent to the server. As a side note, depending on your config and what you're trying to achieve, you shouldn't (generally) append fixed paths to your `proxy_pass` directive. If the `proxy_pass` resides in `location /app/ {` and the URL was `http://.../app/sample/`, then NGINX will pass `/app/sample` for you. Having that fixed path there might have undesired effects.

Comment: I want to restrict "http://192.168.x.y:8080/app/sample#/dashboard" but allow "http://192.168.x.y:8080/app/sample#/view".. Will this be possible?

Comment: If you can't remove the `#` from the URL, then it will have to be done using javascript. Nginx can't help you out.